# Which Openntf Domino API For Domino Designer V10

Tags: xpages

I have installed IBM Notes Designer 10, for the life of me I cannot get the OpenNTF Domino API to be recognised in all my Java Classes. Tried ODA 4.4 and 3.2.1.

I have to go back to 9.0.1 now so I can continue to develop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've bumped the version for 10 in our development branch. Now that the actual release is out, we're going to make sure all is well and release a new ODA version for it.

Comment: Ah thanks Jesse, I've jumped the gun then so anyone using ODA can't upgrade to V10 then I guess. Wish I had known that. Any idea how long it will be, weeks, months, and do you think ODA is short lived with 'high end' developers moving away from XPages?

Comment: @MarkMaden here's a build from the V10 beta forums that you can use until an 'official' release of ODA for V10 is out: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9yi30bipgj24v0/ODA%204.5.0.zip?dl=0

Comment: For info, I wasn't sure if there would be additional Java methods for DQL in 10.0.0 GA release. The technotes have confirmed there aren't.
The probable cause for the problem is that there's a dependency in 9.0.1 versions on a Java package in Ext Lib from OpenNTF that's not included in Ext Lib in core Domino. It's not one we actually use, it must have been at some point though, so we could remove it easily. But because it was referenced, the install process was failing. Installing OpenNTF's Ext Lib v17 would almost certainly have solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info Paul. I have another machine now which hangs when trying to open Notes with ODA, so I have reinstalled without. To be honest I am trying to remove away from these plug ins and just install what comes out of the box. I find them too much hassle and they require a high level of expertise, when things go wrong, even more so when using XPiNC. My problem being all my inhouse developements are now dependant on ODA. Sorry as I know you do some great work, but it is for experts only who have time to spend on it I feel.

Comment: Actually got it working, not sure if it is helpful to you, but my combination was. Upgrade Notes Des to V10, (previous ODA does not appear in 'Application Management' so it must have been removed at this stage)  install ODA 4.5 (then hangs on loading) Uninstall Notes, reinstall with V10 then ODA 4.5 is present without having to reinstall it and it works fine. Probably makes sense to you, I'm just happy it is now working and this may help someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had that problem, too. Jesse found the solution for me in the OpenNtf ODA Slack:
Check Designer - Preferences - Plug-In Development - Target Platform.
Quoting Jesse: "... entries at least for ${eclipse_home} and for a directory inside your Notes data dir, here C:\Notes\Data\workspace\applications\eclipse. If they're missing, modify an existing platform or create a new one and add an "Installation"-type entry for ${eclipse_home} and a "Directory"-type one for the eclipse directory within your data dir." (https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/058650e080e352178525832b00519d2c)

In my case I was missing the .../notes/data/workspace/applications/eclipse entry which I had to add myself.